# Count of all rows with the same value as in current row in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I am working on a report based on logistic software database. We have a table of transactions in warehouses. The warehouses are split into zones and we also have a table of the zones. The problem is that these zones can overlap, so one single transaction takes places in several zones.

I have developed a cube in SSAS that contains a fact table with transaction data and a dimension [m2m Transaction From Position In Zone] that contains Transaction ID and list IDs of all zones, where each transaction takes place. You can see an example of the data below. I would like to create a new measure (New Calculated Measure) that gets me a count of rows with the same Transaction ID. For example transaction 1 takes places in three zones, so the calculated measure should give me 3.

```
Transaction ID| ZoneID | New Calculated Measure
1             | 1      | 3
1             | 2      | 3
1             | 3      | 3
2             | 1      | 4
2             | 2      | 4
2             | 3      | 4
2             | 4      | 4
3             | 2      | 1
```

I started a development with a specifict transaction ID, but I am completly new in MDX and the following code is not working. Could you please help?

```
SUM(EXISTING
Filter(
 [m2m Transaction From Position In Zone].[Transaction ID].members,
 {[m2m Transaction From Position In Zone].[Transaction ID].&[248269]}
 )
,
[Measures].[m2m Transaction From Position In Zone Count]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[New Calculated Measure] AS
COUNT(
    [m2m Transaction From Position In Zone].[Transaction ID].CurrentMember *
    [m2m Transaction From Position In Zone].[ZoneID].[ZoneID].members
)
```

Just count all the zones under current transaction.